# Execute sqlplus from ant fails to find DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: ant, sqlplus

I'm attempting to run a SQL script from within Apache Ant using the execute tag for sqlplus.

```
    <exec dir="src/sql" executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true" output="src/sql/test.sql.err">
        <arg value="${db.login}"/>
        <arg value="@test.sql"/>
    </exec>
```

Sqlplus is working from the command line using the same arguments.

Ant, however returns:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /ade/b/2649109290/oracle/sqlplus/lib/libsqlplus.dylib
```

For the command line I have set:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/instantclient_11_2/
```

Is there an equivalent action I need to take for Ant to find the libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to give SQLcl a try. 
 It's the sql scripting engine from sqldev which is sqlplus , plus a lot more 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/sqlcl-index-2994757.html

The benefit is there there's no libraries it's self contained and uses the JDBC Thin driver for db connectivity.

Here's your ANT example..

```
<project name="sqlcl" basedir=".">
  <property name="db.login" value="klrice/klrice"/>
  <target name="sqlcl">

  <exec dir="." executable="/Users/klrice/Downloads/sqlcl/bin/sql"
        failonerror="true"
        output="sql/test.sql.err">
        <arg value="${db.login}"/>
        <arg value="@sql/dual.sql"/>
    </exec>
</target>
</project>
```

Then running...

```
$ ant sqlcl
Buildfile: /Users/klrice/build.xml

sqlcl:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
587211042:~ klrice$ more sql/test.sql.err

SQLcl: Release 17.4.0 Production on Wed Mar 07 21:59:54 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Mar 07 2018 22:00:08 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

login.sql found in the CWD. DB access is restricted for login.sql.
Adjust the SQLPATH to include the path to enable full functionality.

         1
----------
         1


Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: I had no idea SQLcl existed.  Works perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Great I could help !

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution @kris-rice suggested, here is my implementation including checking for errors...

```
<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- load plsql tox -->
<!-- =================================================================== -->
<target name="compile.plsql.tox" description="compile plsql for tox">
    <echo message="compile.plsql.tox --------------------"/>
    <mkdir dir="tmp/log"/>
    <exec dir="src/sql" executable="sql" failonerror="true" output="src/sql/tox.all.sql.err">
        <arg value="${db.login.tox}"/>
        <arg value="@tox.all.sql"/>
    </exec>
    <echo message="looking for plsql errors -------------------"/>
    <exec dir="src/sql" executable="grep" failonerror="false" resultproperty="found">
        <arg value="LINE/COL ERROR"/>
        <arg value="tox.all.sql.err"/>
    </exec>
    <fail message="plsql compile errors">
        <condition>
            <equals arg1="${found}" arg2="0"/>
        </condition>
    </fail>
    <echo message="looking for line item errors ---------------"/>
    <exec dir="src/sql" executable="grep" failonerror="false" resultproperty="found">
        <arg value="ERROR at"/>
        <arg value="tox.all.sql.err"/>
    </exec>
    <fail message="sql compile errors">
        <condition>
            <equals arg1="${found}" arg2="0"/>
        </condition>
    </fail>
    <echo message="compile.plsql.tox --------------------"/>
</target>
<!-- =================================================================== -->
```